# Image slide left not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slide

I want to slide my image to left when click on the right arrow of the image slider. I cant apply the slide left animation.When click right arrow current image hide and next image is showing but not slide animation is happening

```js
$('#image-content img:first').addClass('active');
        //ON CLICK ON RIGHT ARROW DISPLAY NEXT
        currentIndex = $('#image-content img').index(this) + 1;
        
        $('.right-arrow').on('click', function() {
        if($('#image-content img.active').index() < ($('#image-content img').length - 1)){
        currentIndex++;
        $('#image-content img.active').animate({width: 'toggle'}).removeClass('active').next('#image-content img').addClass('active');     
        }
        else {
        currentIndex = 1;
        $("#image-content img").removeClass("active");
        $('#image-content img').eq(currentIndex - 1).addClass('active');          
        }
        });
        //ON CLICK LEFT ARROW DISPLAY PREVIOUS IMAGE
    
       $('.left-arrow').on('click', function() {
        if ($('#image-content img.active').index() > 0) {
        currentIndex--;
        $('#image-content img.active').removeClass('active').prev('#image-content img').addClass('active');
        } else {
        currentIndex = $('#image-content img').length;
        $("#image-content img").removeClass("active");
        $('#image-content img').eq(currentIndex - 1).addClass('active')
        }
        });
```

```css
#image-content{
    height: 400px;
    width: 100%;
}
#image-content img{
    position: absolute;
    height: auto;
    width: auto;
    max-height: 380px;
    max-width: 100%;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    display: none
}
#image-content img.active{
    display: block
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
                <div class="col-1 text-right nav-direction">
                   <img src="https://d30y9cdsu7xlg0.cloudfront.net/png/136304-200.png" class="img-fluid left-arrow" alt="">
                </div> 
                  <div class="col-9 text-center">
                    <!-- Main Images -->  
                    <div id="image-content"> 
                     <!--(start foreach)-->
                       <img src="http://letssunday.com/assets/upload/product/5aa63613ea17a107011.jpg" class="img-fluid"> 
                       <img src="http://letssunday.com/assets/upload/productImageGallary/5a5da97dc88ad258479.jpeg" class="img-fluid"> 
                       <img src="http://letssunday.com/assets/upload/productImageGallary/5a5da97d45e75220450.jpeg" class="img-fluid"> 
                       <img src="http://letssunday.com/assets/upload/productImageGallary/5a5da97dcf94f110046.jpeg" class="img-fluid"> 
                       <img src="http://letssunday.com/assets/upload/productImageGallary/5a5da97e6268c505542.jpeg" class="img-fluid"> 
                     <!-- (end foreach)-->
                    </div> 
                    <!-- End main Images-->  
  
                  </div>   
                   <div class="col-1 text-left nav-direction">
                   <img src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/ionicons/512/icon-ios7-arrow-right-128.png" class="img-fluid right-arrow" alt="">
                </div> 
              </div>
```

I just want to slide it to left side.Currently working fine except animation.Help Please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's another way for it. Use bootstrap:

```css
div#myCarousel, div#myCarousel > div.carousel-inner, div#myCarousel > div.carousel-inner > div.item{
 /* selector to edit divs */
}
div#myCarousel > div.carousel-inner > div.item > img{
 /* selector to edit images */
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <h2>Carousel Example</h2>  
  <div class="row">
  <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <!-- Indicators -->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ol>

    <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
    <div class="carousel-inner">
      <div class="item active">
        <img class="img-responsive col-xs-12" src="http://letssunday.com/assets/upload/productImageGallary/5a5da97d45e75220450.jpeg" alt="Los Angeles" style="width:100%;">
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <img class="img-responsive col-xs-12" src="http://letssunday.com/assets/upload/productImageGallary/5a5da97dcf94f110046.jpeg" alt="Chicago" style="width:100%;">
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <img class="img-responsive col-xs-12" src="http://letssunday.com/assets/upload/productImageGallary/5a5da97e6268c505542.jpeg" alt="New york" style="width:100%;">
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Left and right controls -->
    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

it's working like a charm

Comment: PD: i also removed the sofa picture because you was not rescaling it and it caused issue too.

Comment: Not working, It does not sliding left after click the next arrow

Comment: It does to me. In which conditios is not working to you? Smartphone? Some browser?

Comment: Google Chrome I'm using

Comment: Me too and is working. Can you update your Google chrome and try other browsers too?

Comment: look my code is working in case of slide concept ,like if ic lcik the right arrow then the curent img would be replaced by new one,Thats cool but But what i asked is when the right arrow clicked the current image should be going to left with animation  effect

Comment: I could have used bootstrap but the problem is i cant change set the image container and i can't apply the image swipe option

Comment: There's a lot of tutorials on ajaxshake, codrops etc, but you're trying to reinvent the wheel

Answer (score -1):

css seems to work, i think there's an issue on youor js.

```js
$('#image-content img:first').addClass('active');
        //ON CLICK ON RIGHT ARROW DISPLAY NEXT
        currentIndex = $('#image-content img').index(this) + 1;
        
        $('.right-arrow').on('click', function() {
        if($('#image-content img.active').index() < ($('#image-content img').length - 1)){
        currentIndex++;
        $('#image-content img.active').animate({width: 'toggle'}).removeClass('active').next('#image-content img').addClass('active');     
        }
        else {
        currentIndex = 1;
        $("#image-content img").removeClass("active");
        $('#image-content img').eq(currentIndex - 1).addClass('active');          
        }
        });
        //ON CLICK LEFT ARROW DISPLAY PREVIOUS IMAGE
    
       $('.left-arrow').on('click', function() {
        if ($('#image-content img.active').index() > 0) {
        currentIndex--;
        $('#image-content img.active').removeClass('active').prev('#image-content img').addClass('active');
        } else {
        currentIndex = $('#image-content img').length;
        $("#image-content img").removeClass("active");
        $('#image-content img').eq(currentIndex - 1).addClass('active')
        }
        });
```

```css
#image-content{
    height: 400px;
    width: 100%;
}
#image-content img{
    position: absolute;
    height: auto;
    width: auto;
    max-height: 380px;
    max-width: 100%;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    display: none;
    transition: 1s;
}
#image-content img.active{
    display: block;

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
                <div class="col-1 text-right nav-direction">
                   <img src="https://d30y9cdsu7xlg0.cloudfront.net/png/136304-200.png" class="img-fluid left-arrow" alt="">
                </div> 
                  <div class="col-9 text-center">
                    <!-- Main Images -->  
                    <div id="image-content"> 
                     <!--(start foreach)-->
                       <img src="http://letssunday.com/assets/upload/product/5aa63613ea17a107011.jpg" class="img-fluid"> 
                       <img src="http://letssunday.com/assets/upload/productImageGallary/5a5da97dc88ad258479.jpeg" class="img-fluid"> 
                       <img src="http://letssunday.com/assets/upload/productImageGallary/5a5da97d45e75220450.jpeg" class="img-fluid"> 
                       <img src="http://letssunday.com/assets/upload/productImageGallary/5a5da97dcf94f110046.jpeg" class="img-fluid"> 
                       <img src="http://letssunday.com/assets/upload/productImageGallary/5a5da97e6268c505542.jpeg" class="img-fluid"> 
                     <!-- (end foreach)-->
                    </div> 
                    <!-- End main Images-->  
  
                  </div>   
                   <div class="col-1 text-left nav-direction">
                   <img src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/ionicons/512/icon-ios7-arrow-right-128.png" class="img-fluid right-arrow" alt="">
                </div> 
              </div>
```

The best option to slide is moving content from out of page to in and the opposite for sliding-out object.

Comment: I've completely copied your code to my code but did not work

Comment: cuz i've not modified all your code, just added transition on css, but you've something wrong on your js. By the way a slider can be done using css only so it's useless to use javascript on there..

Comment: https://codepen.io/DisColow/pen/GgPzWM  There's an example (touching the little balls at the top it changes) you can even add arrows or whatever

Comment: I know there is some problem with my code ,Thats why i've asked question ,so if you pls correct this

Comment: you issue seems to be only that the image is over the arrow, so, sometimes you click over the image instead of click over the arrow.